# Matching list items to automatically update empty fields in R

Tags: r

I have a tibble of Hanja (Chinese) characters with their matching Hangul (Korean) pronunciations.

```
install.packages("searchable") 
require(searchable)

kotr <-
new("Searchable"
    , .Data = structure(list(zh = structure(c(22L, 5L, 9L, 32L, 12L, 31L, 25L, 
17L, 19L, 15L, 29L, 10L, 13L, 1L, 4L, 52L, 51L, 39L, 54L, 41L, 
12L, 46L, 50L, 49L, 42L, 43L, 40L, 48L, 56L, 44L, 45L, 55L, 59L, 
62L, 64L, 60L, 63L, 65L, 58L, 68L, 75L, 74L, 73L, 57L, 72L, 71L, 
70L, 69L, 78L, 86L, 76L, 80L, 93L, 88L, 90L, 98L, 103L, 94L, 
100L, 99L, 108L, 106L, 109L, 39L, 111L, 115L, 113L, 117L, 114L, 
120L, 118L, 130L, 128L, 123L, 124L, 126L, 132L, 134L, 138L, 133L, 
145L, 149L, 143L, 147L, 156L, 155L, 157L, 154L, 151L, 153L, 152L, 
158L, 150L, 162L, 168L, 166L, 164L, 161L, 176L, 178L, 179L, 171L, 
172L, 170L, 184L, 185L, 181L, 194L, 186L, 187L, 189L, 192L, 200L, 
199L, 198L, 202L, 203L, 205L, 211L, 212L, 216L, 213L, 210L, 208L, 
224L, 221L, 229L, 230L, 227L, 223L, 225L, 220L, 219L, 232L, 231L, 
233L, 236L, 238L, 248L, 203L, 242L, 249L, 254L, 252L, 255L, 256L, 
251L, 245L, 202L, 257L, 262L, 260L, 263L, 267L, 266L, 265L, 270L, 
272L, 276L, 274L, 192L, 275L, 281L, 297L, 289L, 288L, 290L, 293L, 
300L, 287L, 278L, 296L, 294L, 295L, 292L, 283L, 284L, 298L, 280L, 
285L, 286L, 282L, 279L, 291L, 299L), .Label = c("八榖", "北斗", 
"北極", "傳舍", "大理", "勾陳", "華蓋", "六甲", "內廚", 
"內階", "女史", "三公", "三師", "尚書", "勢", "四輔", 
"太陽守", "太乙(太一)", "太尊", "天棓", "天廚", 
"天床", "天皇大帝", "天牢", "天理", "天槍", "天乙(天一)", 
"天柱", "文昌", "五帝內座", "相", "玄戈", "陰德", 
"御女[紫微]", "柱史", "紫微右垣", "紫微左垣", "常陳", 
"從官", "虎賁", "九卿", "郎將", "郎位", "靈台", "明堂", 
"內屏", "三台", "少微", "太微右垣", "太微左垣", 
"太子[太微]", "五帝座", "五諸侯", "幸臣", "謁者", 
"長垣", "帛度", "車肆", "帝座", "斗[天市]", "貫索", 
"候", "斛", "宦者", "列肆", "女床", "七公", "市樓", 
"天紀", "天市右垣", "天市左垣", "屠肆", "宗", "宗人", 
"宗正", "衡", "角", "進賢", "庫樓", "南門", "平", 
"平道", "天門", "天田[角]", "周鼎", "柱[角]", "大角", 
"頓頑", "亢", "陽門", "右攝提", "折威", "左攝提", 
"車騎", "氐", "帝席", "梗河", "亢池", "騎官", "騎陣將軍", 
"天輻", "天乳", "招搖", "陣車", "東咸", "罰", "房", 
"鍵閉", "日", "西咸", "積卒", "心", "傳說", "龜", 
"天江", "尾", "魚", "杵[箕]", "箕", "糠", "鱉", "斗", 
"狗", "狗國", "建", "農丈人", "天弁", "天雞", "天淵", 
"天龠", "河鼓", "漸臺", "九坎", "羅堰", "輦道", "牛", 
"天桴", "天田[牛]", "右旗", "織女", "左旗", "敗瓜", 
"扶筐", "瓠瓜", "離珠", "女", "十二國", "天津", "奚仲", 
"敗臼", "哭", "璃瑜", "泣", "司非", "司祿", "司命", 
"司危", "天壘城", "虛", "車府", "杵[危]", "蓋屋", 
"臼", "人", "天鉤", "天錢", "危", "虛梁", "造父", 
"八魁", "北落師門", "鈇鉞", "雷電", "壘壁陣", "室", 
"螣蛇", "天綱", "土公吏", "羽林軍", "壁", "鈇鑕", 
"霹靂", "天廄", "土公", "雲雨", "策", "附路", "閣道", 
"軍南門", "奎", "天溷", "土司空", "外屏", "王良", 
"婁", "天倉", "天大將軍", "天庾", "右更", "左更", 
"大陵", "積尸", "積水", "天船", "天廩", "天囷", "胃", 
"芻蒿", "卷舌", "礪石", "昴", "天阿", "天讒", "天陰", 
"天苑", "月", "畢", "參旗", "九斿", "九州殊口", "天高", 
"天關", "天潢", "天街", "天節", "天園", "威池", "五車", 
"諸王", "柱[畢]", "司怪", "觜", "座旗", "參", "廁", 
"軍井", "屏", "屎", "玉井", "北河", "弧矢", "積薪", 
"井", "軍市", "老人", "南河", "闕丘", "水府", "水位", 
"四瀆", "孫", "天狼", "天樽", "野雞", "丈人", "子", 
"爟", "鬼", "天狗", "天記", "天社", "外廚", "酒旗", 
"柳", "內平", "天稷", "天相", "星", "軒轅", "天廟", 
"張", "東甌", "翼", "軍門", "器府", "青丘", "軫", 
"波斯", "飛魚", "附白", "海山", "海石", "鶴", "火鳥", 
"夾白", "金魚", "孔雀", "馬腹", "馬尾", "蜜蜂", "南船", 
"鳥喙", "三角形", "蛇腹", "蛇首", "蛇尾", "十字架", 
"水委", "小斗", "異雀"), class = "factor"), ko = c("cheonsang", 
"daelii", "naeju", "hyeongwa", "samgong", "sang", "cheonlii", 
"taeyangsu", "taejon", "se", "munchang", "naegye", "samsa", "pal (gǔ)", 
"jeonsa", "ojejwa", "taejataemi", "jonggwan", "haengsin", "gugyeong", 
"samgong", "nae (píng)", "taemijwawon", "taemiuwon", "nangjang", 
"nangwi", "hobun", "somi", "jangwon", "lyeongyeongtae", "myeongdang", 
"alja", "jejwa", "hu", "hwanja", "ducheonsi", "gog", "lyeolyeolsa", 
"geochasa", "sinulu", "jongjeong", "jongin", "jong", "baegdotag", 
"dosa", "cheonsijwawon", "cheonsiuwon", "cheongi", "jinhyeon", 
"jugag", "hyeong", "nammun", "jwaseobje", "donwan", "yangmun", 
"hangji", "choyo", "geochagi", "gijinjanggun", "gigwan", "geonpye", 
"beol", "il", "jonggwan", "jeogjol", "cheongang", "jeonseolseyeol", 
"eo", "gugwigyun", "gang", "jeogi", "cheonyag", "cheongye", "gu", 
"gugug", "nongjangin", "jeomdae", "nalaeon", "cheonjeonu", "gugam", 
"liiju", "haejung", "bugwang", "sibigug", "samyeong", "sanoglog", 
"sawi", "sabi", "gog", "eub", "liyu", "cheonnuluseong", "paegu", 
"gaeog", "heolyangyang", "cheonjeon", "in", "jeowi", "deungsa", 
"togonglii", "ulimimgun", "baebugnaglagsamun", "buwol", "palgoe", 
"togong", "unu", "bujil", "wanglyangyang", "chaeg", "bunolo", 
"gunnammun", "tosagong", "jwagaenggyeong", "ugaenggyeong", "cheonyu", 
"jeogsi", "jeogsu", "cheonleum", "myo", "cheona", "wol", "cheoncham", 
"lyeoyeoseog", "chuho", "cheonga", "cheongo", "jewang", "jupil", 
"wiji", "cheonhwang", "cheonjeol", "gujusugu", "guyu", "ja", 
"sagoe", "jwagi", "gunjeong", "si", "subu", "jeogsu", "jeogsin", 
"suwi", "yagye", "cheonnanglang", "jangin", "ja", "son", "noloin", 
"jeogsi", "gwan", "oeju", "cheongi", "jugi", "cheonsang", "cheonjig", 
"naepyeong", "cheonmyo", "donggu", "(qīng)gu", "gunmun", "tosagong", 
"gibu", "haesan", "sibjaga", "mami", "mabog", "milbong", "samgaghyeong", 
"liijag", "gongjag", "pasa", "sami", "sabog", "sasu", "johwe", 
"hag", "hwajo", "suwi", "bubaeg", "hyeobbaeg", "geumgimeo", "haeseog", 
"bieo", "namseon", "sodu")), .Names = c("zh", "ko"), row.names = c(NA, 
185L))
    , type = "std"
    , options = list())
```

I would like to match the Korean terms on this list to those on the following list so that empty field in the latter can be updated automatically.

```
data <-
structure(list(sno = list("ko001", "ko013", "ko016", "ko036", 
    "ko040", "ko041", "ko050", "ko053", "ko217", "ko218"), ko = c("JuJeong", 
"ChoYo", "HangJii", "Eo", "Kii", "WaeJeo", "Byeol", "JaamDae", 
"SamGong", "SamGong"), en = c("Holy Kettle", "Flutting Flag", 
"Oar for visitor", "Fish", "Winnow", "Outer Pestle", "Snapping Turtle", 
"River adjoining Tower", "Three Ministers", "Three Ministers"
), zh = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "三官", "三官"), 
    connect = list(c("2", "65721", "64792", "64792", "64852"), 
        c("1", "71075", "71075"), c("6", "69612", "70327", "70327", 
        "70400", "70400", "69389", "69389", "68707", "68707", 
        "68498", "68498", "69612"), c("1", "87569", "87569"), 
        c("3", "88635", "89931", "89931", "90185", "90185", "89642"
        ), c("2", "90830", "90414", "90414", "90568"), c("13", 
        "92953", "92308", "92308", "91494", "91494", "90982", 
        "90982", "90887", "90887", "91875", "91875", "92989", 
        "92989", "93174", "93174", "93825", "93825", "94114", 
        "94114", "94160", "94160", "94005", "94005", "93542", 
        "93542", "92953"), c("3", "93194", "92420", "92420", 
        "92791", "92791", "94481"), c("3", "66234", "64906", 
        "64906", "65550", "65550", "66234"), c("3", "52353", 
        "51448", "51448", "50933", "50933", "52353"))), .Names = c("sno", 
"ko", "en", "zh", "connect"), row.names = c(1L, 13L, 16L, 36L, 
40L, 41L, 50L, 53L, 217L, 218L), class = "data.frame")
```

Here's what I tried, but none of the code below seemed work.

```
lapply(kotr$ko, function(x) grep(x, data$ko))
lapply(data$ko, function(x) grep(x, kotr$ko))
mapply(agrep, kotr$ko, data$ko)
kotr$ko %in%  data$ko
data$ko %in% kotr$ko
```

Yet, it is obvious that there are matches.

```
grep("samgong", data$ko, ignore.case = T)
[1]  9 10
> grep("samgong", kotr$ko, ignore.case = T)
[1]  5 21
```

Where did I go wrong and how should I go about doing this?

---

**Matching the data**

@akrun:

I managed to subset the data with this:

```
z <- lapply(data$ko, function(x) grep(paste0("^", x, "$"), kotr@.Data$ko, ignore.case = TRUE))
z <- melt(z)

> kotr$zh[z$value]
[1] 招搖 魚   三公 三公 三公 三公
300 Levels: 八榖 北斗 北極 傳舍 大理 勾陳 ... 異雀
> data$zh[z$L1]
[1] ""     ""     "三官" "三官" "三官" "三官"
```

But assigning the values of `kotr` to `data` gave a weird result:

```
> data$zh[z$L1] <- kotr$zh[z$value]
> data$zh
 [1] ""    "103" ""    "117" ""    ""    ""   
 [8] ""    "12"  "12"
```

Comment: Please check the `kotr` dput output.  It seems to be incomplete

Comment: @akrun: Just a closing parenthesis is missing. I've just fixed it.

Comment: I get `Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) : 
  “Searchable” is not a defined class`

Comment: You need this: `install.packages("searchable")
require(searchable)`

Comment: Please check the code in my answer

Comment: If you look at `z$L1` i.e. `z$L1#
[1]  2  4  9  9 10 10`  there are duplicate index,

Comment: Yes, I was wondering how to deal with duplicates. It is another issue, actually. Are we able to ignore this for now?

Comment: You can have a `list` column i.e. `lst <- split(z$value, z$L1); data$zh[as.numeric(names(lst))] <- lapply(lst, function(x) kotr$zh[x])` or `paste` the elements as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to `?Searchable`

> S4 method for signature 'Searchable'

```
str(kotr)
#Formal class 'Searchable' [package "searchable"] with 3 slots
#  ..@ .Data  :List of 2
#  .. ..$ zh: Factor w/ 300 levels "八榖","北斗",..: 22 5 9 32 12 31 25 17 19 15 ...
#  .. ..$ ko: chr [1:185] "cheonsang" "daelii" "naeju" "hyeongwa" ...
#  .. ..- attr(*, "row.names")= int [1:185] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
#  ..@ type   : chr "std"
#  ..@ options: list()
```

so we need to extract using `@`

```
lapply(data$ko, function(x) grep(x, kotr@.Data$ko, ignore.case = TRUE))
```

Comment: The search for "Eo" resulted a long list of elements containing the string "eo" in it. I was unable to narrow the search with the following regex in grep: `^x$`. How do I quote regex with a variable?

Comment: @Sati Did you meant `lapply(data$ko, function(x) grep(paste0("^", x, "$"), kotr@.Data$ko, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Comment: `lapply(data$ko, function(x) grep(^x$, kotr@.Data$ko, ignore.case = TRUE))`

Comment: @Sati I think I got what you tried.  Please try the code in the earlier comment

Comment: Yes, your code did the work. Didn't realize that I could use `paste` with `grep`.

Comment: How do I go on to update `data`? `z <- lapply(data$ko, function(x) grep(paste0("^", x, "$"), kotr@.Data$ko, ignore.case = TRUE))
data$zh[z,]`
`> data$zh[z]
Error in data$zh[z] : 無效的下標類型 'list'`

Comment: @Sati  What is `ko.data` ?  You had `data` and `kotr` showed here

Comment: Sorry, got mixed up with my actual variable name. `data` over here is a subset of `ko.data`. Error is the same.

Comment: @Sati There are couple of problem in the subsetting `data$zh[z,]`. `data$zh` is a vector of length 10 and `z` is a `list` with some  numeric index where it is 57, 68, 5, 21 etc as numbers.  It is not clear how you subset it

Comment: Would it be easier if `kotr` had not been a `searchble` list?

Comment: @Sati I think it is based on the index here please check the `z` values and `data$zh` length.

Comment: `length(z)` is the length of `data$zh`.

Comment: @Sati Yes, that is true, but the values in `z` is `unlist(z)#
[1] 57 68  5 21  5 21`  So, if you are using it to subset the `data$zh`, it looks for the 57th, 68th, ... elements which doesn't exist as it is of length 10

Comment: They index to the position number of the matching term in `kotr`, so `kotr$zh[57]` gives the match `招搖` to `data$zh[2]`, for example.

Comment: @Sati If you are trying to subset on kotr, it would work `kotr@.Data$zh[unlist(z)]`

Comment: The subsetting worked, but the assigning failed. See my edited question above.